# Port forwarding not working on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, port-forwarding, google-compute-engine, windows-firewall

I've created a rule in google cloud to allow inbound connections, but the port won't open.  Can't connect through telnet or online port checkers.  Can anyone tell me what could the issue be?  I included all my rules below as well but it's port 27015 I'm trying to open and on a Windows server (with firewall disabled)

[Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SY80.png)

[Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Dci.png)

Comment: But your "firewall" allows all traffic anyway! What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The specific port I need open is still showing as closed even with the rules to allow all trafic

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean the port 27015 isn't open.  There's no other way to explain it.

Comment: That actually doesn't say anything. You need to be specific about what you are doing. Why do you expect the port to be open? How are you checking whether the port is open?

Answer (score 0):

The string you entered into `Protocols and Ports` is using a semi-colon to separate `TCP:27015` and `UDP:27105` which is invalid syntax, you need to use a comma `,`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check following the previous answer posted by the community member, if the issue still persists, you can try the following:

1. Check to see if the port is open or closed using [nmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap).

## nmap [ip_address]

2. Make sure there is no firewall running inside the VM blocking those connections.
3. Check from inside the VM and make sure that service is running on that port.

## telnet

4. You also need to verify if the application running on your instance is [listening on port](https://serverfault.com/questions/895580/open-443-on-google-compute-instance) (in this lnk it talks about 443 but in your case it is TCP:27015) . To check this, try with this command.

## sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN

In the output, if you don't see the application beside port number, check if your VM is [correctly configured](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-open-port-443) to ports for your application.